# How to create snap setting buttons in scene view or inspector view based on a selected game object

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity-editor

I am using 9 different snap settings to move 3 different objects around in my scene view (3 for each object). Manually adjusting these settings is really a pain. How can create dynamic snap settings buttons within the scene view (or inspector) that change when I select a game object? Therefore at any given time, only the 3 snap settings I need for a game object would be available through the buttons.